# Deny admin routes for specific and not logged users

Tags: cakephp

I have two groups id :

Group 1 => Admins

Group 2 => Users

I'm looking for a way to deny the access for the users which are not admin (so group 2 and not logged) . The function isAuthorized doesn't work, i mean it's always return true, i just don't know why . Thanks for your help

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home');

        if(isset($this->request->params["prefix"]) && $this->request->params["prefix"] == "admin"){
            $this->layout = "admin";
        } else {
            $this->layout = "default";
        }

    }

    public function isAuthorized() {
        parent::isAuthorized();
        if(isset($this->request->params["prefix"]) && $this->request->params["prefix"] == "admin" && $this->Auth->user('group_id') === 1){
            return true; 
        }
        else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    }

}
```

PagesController

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController {

/**
 * This controller does not use a model
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $uses = array();

/**
 * Displays a view
 *
 * @param mixed What page to display
 * @return void
 * @throws NotFoundException When the view file could not be found
 *  or MissingViewException in debug mode.
 */

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }

    public function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public function admin_index() {
        $title_for_layout = 'Dashboard';
        $this->set(compact('title_for_layout'));
    }

}
```

routes

```
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
    Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

Comment: What are you using to define `admin` action? Do you set something in the `routes.php` file?

Comment: I added the routes . If the users want to go to http://www.mywebsite.com/admin they can have access , the not logged user and the group id 2 ... I just wan tto allow the access for the admin (group id 1)

Answer (score 2):

To auto add prefix from action like `admin_` you need to add the following line in your `core.php` file:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Then, the action `PagesController::admin_index` is accessible by `/admin/pages/index` instead of `/pages/admin_index` and the `admin` param is set to true so you can check it using `$this->params['admin']` (see my code bellow).

Actually, in CakePHP all routes are denied by default but you allow all routes in `PagesController` by doing `$this->Auth->allow()` in the beforeFilter, you need to add an exception for `admin`.

To do so, in your `AppController`:

```
<?php

class AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home');
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
            'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        )
    ) ;

    public beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter() ;
        // Allow everything to not logged user except admin pages
        if (isset($this->params["admin"]) 
            && $this->params["admin"]) {
            $this->Auth->deny() ;
        }
        else {
            $this->Auth->allow() ;
        }
    }

    public isAuthorized() {
        if (isset($this->params["admin"]) 
            && $this->params["admin"]) {
            return $this->Auth->user('group_id') === 1 ;
        }
        return parent::isAuthorized() ;
    }

} ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't change anything, the not logged and the group id 2 can have access to the controller page (admin_index) . I edited my post, thanks

Comment: @user3790914 I've updated my answer. You need to set prefix in `core.php` to allow use of method with name like `admin_index`.

Comment: It was seted, the /admin works, it's just that everybody can access of the content of the admin_index view .

Comment: @user3790914 As I said I've updated my answer (not only the beginning), I think you're doing a wrong check for admin page, I use `$this->params['admin']` and it works on my own website.

Comment: if they wan to access (not loged or group id 2) to http://mywebsite.com/users/add they can't (ACL works), if they want to access to http://mywebsite.com/admin/pages/index or http://mywebsite.com/admin/users/add they can .

Comment: @user3790914 With only ACL setted on the `Auth` component, the `isAuthorized` method is not used by CakePHP. You need to specify `Controller` in the `authorize` array as I do in my answer.